# Иконки бэкгроунды и прочее

Tags: веб-дизайн, иконки

Какими медиа-ресурсами пользуетесь Вы, для создания своих программ / сайтов ?

Где вы берете иконки и другие медиа файлы ? Может кто знает интересные ссылки по теме ?

вот что известно мне:

1. [famfamfam](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/)
2. [iconizer](http://iconizer.net/)
3. [iconogratis](http://www.iconesgratis.net/)
4. [iconpicker](http://iconpicker.deviantech.ru/)
5. [led24](http://led24.de/iconset/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://www.deviantart.com/ - *тут очень много всякой - всячины графической*
- http://iconfinder.com/
- http://google.com - *это мой
     любимый)))*

**UPD**: еще один нашел с хорошей и довольно полезной графой)

- http://freebiesbooth.com/

Comment: ооо да Гугл любимый и незаменимый)))

Comment: Спасибо) Посмотрю на досуге.

Answer (score 1):

[spritecow.com](http://www.spritecow.com/) - клевый сервис для вырезания картинок из неоднородных спрайтов и последующей генерацией в css.

[jqueryui icon set](http://jqueryui.com)- Качаем фреймвок, там есть приятный  набор спрайтов разных  цветов с иконками 16x16 и фреймворк в виде jqueryUI к нему, но я предпочитаю делать все вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Также, можно поискать на [vremenno.net](http://vremenno.net/search/?q=%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&cx=partner-pub-8285102953093207%3A6gfwi415siu&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=utf-8) - иногда там попадаются дельные вещи.